# Replace submit button with onclick event if Javascript enabled

Tags: javascript, button

Keeping with the idea of progressive implementation, I have a simple page refresh button on my page. Is there an elegant way to turn that button into an onclick="ajaxfunction()" event if javascript is enabled?

All I've come up with having two buttons, and hiding one with CSS -- which seems a bit clunky.

Note, I have the ajax call working, etc - I just want that $%@# button to switch over...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've a `form` with a `button` type of `submit`:

```
<button id="sbut" type="submit" ...>OK</button>
```

You can do this:

```
function chgButton () {
    var button = document.getElementById('sbut');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.addEventListener('click', ajaxfunction,false);
    return;
}

window.onload = function () {
    chgButton();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Attach an event listener to the submit button which listens to the `click` event and cancels the event. With prototype it would be something like this:

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
    $('mysubmitbuttonid').observe('click',function(event){
        new Ajax.Request(...);
        Event.stop(event);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I haven't used plain JS for years! Too much browser quirks to take into account :)

Comment: Interesting... I'm new to javascript, so am enjoying learning "the hard way." I also don't have enough js (yet) on my site to justify JQuery's added heft. <-- perhaps this statement comes from a point of ignorance ;)

Comment: It's good to learn the hard way. This gives you a better vision of what's going on, and in some cases it may be preferrable to stick with plain JS than to rely on third-party libraries (which forces you to update from time to time). It depends on the situation. As Perl folks would say, TMTOWTDI :)